# Find the shortest path enclosed by two functions.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

Let $f, g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$  be two  continuous functions such that $$f(x)<g(x)\ \ \forall\ x\in(a,b)$$

Let $P_1\ (x_1,\ y_1)$ and $P_2\ (x_2,\ y_2)$ such that $$a \le x_1,
x_2\le b\ ,\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(x_1) < y_1 < g(x_1)\  and\\ f(x_2) < y_2 < g(x_2)$$

Describe a general way to find the shortest (in length) continuous function $h$ that connects the two points and $$f(x)<h(x)<g(x)\ \ \forall\ x\in[x_1,x_2]$$
**Notes**

1. You may also consider the case
   $$f(x)\le h(x)\le g(x)$$
   and (optionally):
   $$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(x_1) \le y_1\le g(x_1)\  and\\ f(x_2) \le y_2\le g(x_2)$$
2. You may make any extra necessary assumptions (e.g. differentiability) provided that the problem does not become trivial.

(Edit 6:)

3. If you already know the answer telling me which topics I should look into is enough (and you probably don't need to read further).

(Edit 4:)

**Comment**

Proposed solution (by Christian Blatter):

"Stretch a rubber band from P1 to P2. This band will be straight whenever it does not lie along one of the boundary curves."

If this statement is true, I would very much like to see a proof.

(Edit 7:)

(Pointed out by TonyK) There's not always a function that satisfies the original argument (not the things in the Notes section). There may only be an infimum for the length of $h$.

(Edit 5:)

**How the problem arose**

I was walking on the street which was formed by the arcs of two concentric circles. I was trying to find what trajectory I should follow so that walking "a given angle" around the circle and simultaneously "crossing the street" I would walk the least. If the line that connects the two points is on the street then problem is trivial. If not I should either:

1. Follow the obvious tangent from $P_1$ to the small circle, walk as much as necessary on this circle to "find" the tangent from this circle to the other point etc. Or
2. I should move in such a way so the distance between me and the center of the circles changes at some rate (possibly constant) making a spiral like path.

Until now I don't know which option is the best.

The original question is more general. The problem can be generalized even further of course. For example one could consider instead of the functions f, g a set of points. Also the problem can be extended in higher dimensions.

**To save time**

The post has been edited to include the useful comments made to it. You may skip reading them. However, I encourage you to look at the attempted answers and their comments.

Comment: What do you mean by *shortest* continuous function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Arnav_Mahajav Shortest means of shortest length. I thought it was quite obvious by the title. Intuitively it would be $h:[x_1, x_2] \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos I am aware of that policy. I tried to keep the post as consise as possible. Any statement resembling "I dunno what to do, I'm stuck at the beginning" seemed redundant.

Comment: In general, there will be no shortest path such that $f(x)<h(x)<g(x)$. You need instead $f(x)\le h(x)\le g(x)$. These things matter!

Comment: The trajectory for the example you give is not a spiral. It is two straight lines joined by a circular arc.

Comment: I would simplify the problem first: consider only one function, say $f$, and find the admissible $h\geq f$ that minimizes the length (functional) $\int_a^b \sqrt{|h'(x)|^2+1}\operatorname d x$ with the boundary conditions $h(x_1)=y_1$ and $h(x_2)=y_2$.  This is essentially a constrained minimization problem in an infinite dimensional space of functions $h$ (to be defined).  You may also assume $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$, $y_1=y_2=0$ by appropriately rescaling and shifting the $x$ and $y$ coordinates (intuitively this is possible because minimal paths are invariant with respect to linear transformation).

Comment: @TonyK I don't understand the first comment, consider the trivial case f: y=0, g: y=2 and two points in between

Comment: Stretch a rubber band from $P_1$ to $P_2$. This band will be straight whenever it does not lie along one of the boundary curves.

Comment: @Peter, that's why I said "in general". The point is that the shortest path will usually touch $f$ or $g$, so you can't have strict inequality.

Comment: If the given angle can be more than $2\pi$, then the circular arc just has to wrap around the circle more than once. That is not really a spiral (you might call it a degenerate spiral).

Comment: @TonyK I get it now, you would have an infimum for the length. Although I think the use of the word general is not quite accurate. It's the analogous of saying that functions are not differentialable in general.

Comment: @Christian_Blatter  I'm still not quite convinced. For example consider the "circle" road,  (intuitively) it seems in some occasions better to spiral your way through the circles than going all the way down to the small circle and then up again.

Comment: Are the paths  tangent to two concentric circles? can you sketch it?

Comment: What I say in the post is that the two lines of the path are tangents to the small circle from the two points. It will help if you imagine the rubber band.

Comment: @Oskar_Limka what you are describing is indeed a constrained optimization problem but for a function of functions! I would really like to see the solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the boundary functions are differentiable.

If the path goes through any two points in the strict region between the two functions (yellow, below), it must do so in a straight line (of course), as that's the shortest distance between those points.

Any other section of a path must include sections along the boundary functions themselves.

The touching of such sections must occur at a point where the straight line is *tangent* to the boundary function, otherwise you could replace that section with a shorter segment that *is* tangent (see second figure).

Hence the solution is an alternating path of straight segments tangent to the boundary functions, then sections of the boundary functions, as shown here:

[image]

This is indeed the "rubber band" solution, but the previous answerer did not stress the key fact that the rubber band must touch a boundary curve *as a tangent*.

To see that the *tangent* transition is always shortest, just study this figure and compare the red and green paths between the two black points:

[image]

Comment: The steps you described are not enough to draw $h$ you still need some intuition.

Comment: @PeterSoulos:  No... that is false.  I've published a paper on this:  https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.15423

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **attempt** at making a claim and proving it.  Essentially it is "be as close to the straight line connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$ as possible"

> Claim: Denote the line segment from $P_1$ to $P_2$ by $L$.  Then the continuous function $h$ on $[x_1 , x_2]$ given by
> $$ h(x) = \begin{cases}
>  L(x) & \mbox{ if } f(x) < L(x) < g(x) \\
>  f(x) & \mbox{ if } L(x) \leq f(x) \\
>  g(x) & \mbox{ if } L(x) \geq g(x)
> \end{cases} $$
> is the shortest continuous path connecting $P_1$ to $P_2$ such that $f \leq h \leq g$

The general case for $h$ follows from the cases below.

If $h(x)=L(x)$ for all $x \in [x_1 , x_2 ]$, then we are done since the shortest path between two points is the line segment joining them

Assume WLOG that that $h(x) > L(x)$ for some $x$, and $h \leq g$ (if we flip the inequality directions and replace $g$ with $f$, the proof is equivalent just "upside down").  But assume by way of contradiction that there exists a continuous function $H$ satisfying the problem such that $H \neq h$ and the arc length of $H$ on $[x_1 , x_2]$ is less than that of $h$.  Then
$$ H \geq h \geq L $$
and there $\exists x$ such that
$$ H(x) > h(x) $$
These facts show that $H$ "deviates" strictly more than $h$ from $L$ (which is the shortest possible path). Actually we can approximate $h$ by a polygonal path $\gamma_n$ and $H$ by a polygonal path $\Gamma_n$, where $n$ is the number of line segments in the polygonal path, such that $h(x) \in \gamma_n$ and $H(x) \in \Gamma_n$.   Then
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \gamma_n = h $$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \Gamma_n = H $$
and
$$ arclength(\gamma_n) < arclength(\Gamma_n) \quad \forall n>1 $$
From these 3 facts we conclude
$$ arclength(h) < arclength(H) $$
as desired as it completes the contradiction

Comment: I had trouble understanding some parts of your answer, but what I understood is that you didn't implement the rubber band rather than the "thread". The concept of the rubber band is having tangent lines. You can intuitively understand that the thread theory is wrong. (And it can be proved easily with a counterexample, consider the post's example).

Comment: I dont really understand the counterexample (could you include a picture perhaps?).  But as for the question of continuous functions on $[a,b]$, I don't see anything wrong with the proof (of course it could be but I'm looking and don't see it)

Comment: This is the "thread": https://postimg.cc/FfCQBpyZ and the band: https://postimg.cc/wtgvpwsY

Comment: Don't pay attention attention to the order of the letters, just the arrows.

Comment: In case you agree with me it would be helpful not to delete the answer and instead to find what went wrong with the proof.

Comment: About the proof I think there is a problem here: $$arclength(\gamma_n) < arclength(\Gamma_n) \quad \forall n>1$$

Answer (score 0):

$\def\m{\mu}$What follows is a sketch of a solution using the calculus of variations.

Consider $h(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)\le h(x)\le g(x)$ where $(a,h(a))$ and $(b,h(b))$ are given.
We wish to minimize
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{1+h'(x)^2}dx$$
with respect to $h(x)$ subject to the above constraints.

We introduce Lagrange multipliers $\m_1(x),\m_2(x)\ge 0$
to impose the constraints $f(x)\le h(x)$ and $h(x)\le g(x)$ and instead extremize
$$d(h(x),\m_1(x),\m_2(x)) = \int_a^b\left[
\sqrt{1+h'(x)^2}
+ \m_1(x)(f(x)-h(x))
+ \m_2(x)(h(x)-g(x)\right]dx.$$
We maximize $d$ with respect to $\m_1(x)$ and $\m_2(x)$ and minimize with respect to $h(x)$.
Below we consider how the first constraint is imposed by this choice.
The second constraint can be understood similarly.

When the first constraint is satisfied but not active, $f(x)<h(x)$ or $f(x)-h(x)<0$, we have $\m_1(x)=0$.
(We maximize with respect to $\m_1$ and $\m_1(x)(f(x)-h(x))\le0$.
Thus, $\m_1(x)=0$.)

When the first constraint is satisfied and active, $f(x)=h(x)$, then $\m_1(x)\ge0$.

When the first constraint is not satisfied,
$f(x)>h(x)$, then $\m_1(x)\rightarrow\infty$ and so $d\rightarrow\infty$.
Thus, the length of the path will not be minimized when the constraint is not satisfied.

Varying with respect to $h(x)$, $\m_1(x)$ and $\m_2(x)$, we find
\begin{align*}
\frac{h''(x)}{(1+h'(x)^2)^{3/2}} &= \m_2(x)-\m_1(x) \tag{1} \\ 
h(x) &= f(x), 
    & \textrm{unless $\m_1(x)=0$} \\
h(x) &= g(x). 
    & \textrm{unless $\m_2(x)=0$} 
\end{align*}
In a region for which the constraint is satisfied and not active we find
$h''(x) = 0$.
Thus, $h(x)$ is a straight line in this region.
Otherwise, when the constraint is satisfied and active, we have that $h(x)$ is given by either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$.
In a region where the first constraint is satisfied and not active we have $\m_1(x)=0$.
In a region where the first constraint is satisfied and active we have $\m_1(x) = -f''(x)/(1+f'(x)^2)^{3/2}$.
Assuming that $f''(x)$ is piecewise continuous we find that $\m_1(x)$ is at worst piecewise continuous.
(Similar remarks can be made for $\m_2$ and $g$.)
Integrating both sides of (1) over a generic infinitesimal region, we find that $h'(x)$ must be continuous.
Thus, to find the optimal path we find the shortest differentiable path consisting of straight line segments and subsets of the graphs of $f$ and $g$ between the two points in question.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\vu{{\bf u}}
\def\vv{{\bf v}}
\newcommand\comp[1]{\langle #1\rangle}
\def\c{\xb^*} 
\def\cc{c'}
\def\m{\mu}
\def\pa{P_1}
\def\xa{x_1}
\def\ya{y_1}
\def\pb{P'}
\def\xb{c}
\def\yb{f(\xb)}
\def\pc{P_2}
\def\xc{x_2}
\def\yc{f(\xc)}$Here we prove a claim in the answer by @DavidG.Stork's that the "tangent transition" gives the shortest path.

Let $\pa=\pa(\xa,\ya)$, $\pb=(\xb,f(\xb))$, and $\pc=(\xc,f(\xc))$.
Assume that $\xa\ne \xc$, $\xa\le \xb\le \xc$, and $\ya>f(\xa)$.
Define
$$h(x;\xb) = \begin{cases}
L(x;\xb), & \xa\le x< \xb \\
f(x),   & \xb\le x\le \xc,
\end{cases}$$
where $L(x;\xb)=\ya+\frac{f(\xb)-\ya}{\xb-\xa}(x-\xa)$.
Thus,
$(x,h(x;\xb))$ for $x\in[\xa,\xc]$ is the curve consisting of the line segment from $\pa$ to $\pb$ and the path from $\pb$ to $\pc$ along the curve determined by $f$.
The curve specified by $h(x;\xb)$ is admissible if
$h(x;\xb)\ge f(x)$ for $x\in[\xa,\xc]$, that is, if $L(x;\xb)\ge f(x)$ for $x\in[\xa,\xb]$.
We assume that $f$ is differentiable on $[\xa,\xc]$.
See Figure 1 below.

The length the path is
$$d(\xb) = \sqrt{(\xb-\xa)^2+(f(\xb)-\ya)^2} 
+\int_{\xb}^{\xc}\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}dt.$$
Thus,
$$d'(\xb)=\frac{\xb-\xa+(f(\xb)-\ya)f'(\xb)}{\sqrt{(\xb-\xa)^2+(f(\xb)-\ya)^2}} - \sqrt{1+f'(\xb)^2}.$$
The critical points are given by the $\xb=\c\in(\xa,\xc)$ such that $d'(\c)=0$.
Let $\vu=\comp{\xb-\xa,f(\xb)-\ya}$ and $\vv=\comp{1,f'(\xb)}$.
Then
$d'(\xb) = \left(\vu\cdot\vv-|\vu||\vv|\right)/|\vu|.$
Note that $d'(\xb)=0$ only if $\vu=\alpha\vv$ for some $\alpha>0$.
This immediately implies that
$$f'(\c) = \frac{f(\c)-\ya}{\c-\xa}$$
for any $\c$ such that $d'(\c)=0$.
Thus, $h(x;\c)$ is differentiable, that is, the line through $\pa$ and $\pb(\c,f(\c))$ is tangent to the curve determined by $f$ at $x=\c$.
See Figures 2 and 5 below.

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$d'(\xb)\le 0.$$
Naively, we may have expected to find a local minimum for $d$, but instead we have that $d$ decreases as we approach $\c$ and then decreases further as we pass by $\c$.
To understand this, consider
$L(x;\c)-f(x)$
near $x=\c$.
We find
$L(x;\c)-f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}f''(\c)(x-\c)^2+O((x-\c)^3)$.
Assuming that $f''(\c)\ne0$, this implies that $f''(\c)< 0$.
(Otherwise the curve would not be admissible.)
Further, note that
$L(\c;\c+\e)-f(\c) = \frac{1}{2}f''(\c)\e^2+O(\e^3)<0$
for $\e>0$ sufficiently small.
This implies that curves corresponding to $h(x;c)$ for $c\in(\c,\c+\e)$ are not admissible.
See Figure 3 below.

Thus, disregarding admissibility, $d$ is a nonincreasing function of $\xb$ for which $d'(\xb)=0$ only if the slopes of
$L(x;\xb)$ and $f(x)$ agree at $\xb$.
By requiring only admissible paths we can see that $d$ is a nonincreasing function with regions corresponding to nonadmissible paths removed.
These regions will be of the form $(\c,\cc)$, where $\cc$ is the smallest $\xb\in(\c,\xc)$ such that $L(\cc;\xb)=f(\cc)$, if such an $\cc$ exists.
(If not, the region is $(\c,\xc)$.)
See Figure 4 below.

If $f(x)\le L(x;\xc)$ for all $x\in[\xa,\xc]$, then the shortest path is given by $L(x;\xc)$.
If $f(x)>L(x;\xc)$ for some $x\in[\xa,\xc]$ then, by the mean value theorem, there will be a $\c\in(\xa,\xc)$ such that $f'(\c)=0$.
Let $\{\c_i\}$ be the collection of such values.
Since $d$ is nonincreasing, the shortest path with be given by $h(x;c)$, where $c$ is the largest member of this set.
Thus, to minimize $d$ we choose a straight line between $\pa$ and $\pc$ if possible, otherwise we choose the "furthest" tangent transition.
See Figure 6 below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]